# EventBus: What are some differences among each thread modes?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, event-bus

According to [EventBus doc](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md), there are 4 types of thread modes which `EventBus` uses to deliver threads:

> - `onEvent()`
>
>   - PostThread
>   - Good for simple tasks
> - `onEventMainThread()`
>
>   - MainThread
>   - a.k.a. UI Thread
>   - Good for UI changes
> - `onEventBackgroundThread()`
>
>   - BackgroundTread
>   - Using single thread, delivering events sequentially.
>   - Good for execution requiring moderate amount of time.
> - `onEventAsync()`
>
>   - Async
>   - Using separate threads.
>   - Good for execution requiring longer time

### Question

1. What are some criteria I should examine before I use `onEventBackgroundThread()` over `onEventAsync()`, or vice versa? What would be some examples of using one over the other with obvious advantages?
2. Which thread modes should each of the following functions use?

   - Getting the device status -- GPS location of the device (i.e. `android.location`), Internet connectivity status (i.e. `ConnectivityManager`, `NetworkInfo`).
   - Making simple HTTP requests to receive text (e.g. JSON), taking anywhere between 1000ms to 5000ms, average 2000ms.
   - Making simple HTTP requests to load images with file sizes between 50kb to 1500kb (exact sizes are unknown to client, before making requests to server).
   - Caching data to internal database (e.g. `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite`, etc).

Comment: Are you going to leave this question alone this time? I was halfway through typing in an answer last time, at which point you deleted the question. :-(

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry :( Shortly after, I thought I was going to rewrite the entire question, but I ended up reposting it...

Answer (score 4):

> What are some criteria I should examine before I use onEventBackgroundThread() over onEventAsync(), or vice versa? What would be some examples of using one over the other with obvious advantages?

Well, it's pretty much as the bullets outline. If you don't mind queued, one-at-a-time processing (or perhaps you *want* it for simpler thread safety), use `onEventBackgroundThread()`. If you need to do several of them in parallel, particularly if they are I/O-bound, you'd use `onEventAsync()`.

> Which thread modes should each of the following functions use?
>
> GPS location of the device (i.e. android.location)

None of the above. `LocationManager` and the fused location API have their own asynchronous options; I'd use those. Once you get the location handed to you, you could post an event with the location data, but then the threading is dictated by the subscribers to that event, not the poster.

> Internet connectivity status (i.e. ConnectivityManager, NetworkInfo)

None of the above, as AFAIK `getNetworkInfo()` is not an expensive call.

> Making simple HTTP requests to receive text (e.g. JSON), taking anywhere between 1000ms to 5000ms, average 2000ms.

None of the above. I'd use Retrofit or another HTTP client library that offers asynchronous options. If for some reason you absolutely have to do the HTTP I/O yourself, it would depend on how frequently this was happening. If, for example, you might fall behind because you fire off several of these in rapid succession, use `onEventAsync()` so they can run in parallel.

> Making simple HTTP requests to load images with file sizes between 50kb to 1500kb (exact sizes are unknown to client, before making requests to server).

None of the above. Use Picasso, Universal Image Loader, or any of the other image-loading libraries, as they all have asynchronous options, and you really need those anyway for the image processing logic. If for some reason you absolutely have to do the HTTP I/O yourself, it'd follow the same rules as I described for the previous item.

> Caching data to internal database (e.g. SharedPreferences, SQLite, etc).

Assuming that you're not using some wrapper library here that might offer asynchronous operation, this probably can be handled via `onEventBackgroundThread()`. That would also give you the advantage of ensuring serialized operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even with Picasso, Universal Image Loader, Retrofit, etc., with asynchronous options, can't we use `EventBus` to dispatch the result? The result of Universal Image Loader invokes `onLoadingComplete()`. I have `EventBus.getDefault().post()` within it to dispatch the result, to let other fragments or activities know what's updated.

Comment: @melvkim: "can't we use EventBus to dispatch the result?" -- sure! That's a fine plan. However, your question was about the threading, and the threading is dictated not by the work of the *poster* of the event, but by the work of the *subscriber* to the event.